# Difference in scoring between multivalued field and tokenized field

Tags: solr, indexing, lucene

For example I have several tags per document. I can

- index them as single text string spliting by space uisng WhiteSpaceTokenizer. (example "tag1 tag2 tag3")
- add them separatly to single field name multiple times using KeywordAnalyzer (
  example 
  `doc.addField("tags1", "tag1"); 
  doc.addField("tags", "tag2");
  doc.addField("tags", "tag23)`
  )

Both approaches will work. The question is how different will be scoring for those types of indexing? (i.e. field normalization factor, tf/idf count, field length calucaltion, slope factor etc)

Answer (score 1):

Lucene will concatenate all the values for a multivalued filed behind the scene anyway, so it'd not be much different than your first case, if at all. If you use tags only as filters (give me all docs tagged with tag2), then you definitely won't see any difference.

Comment: does it mean that I can search for phrases using 2nd approach?

Comment: why not? (this is annoying, min 15char comment length...)

Comment: Because it is unexpected behavior, if I index "a", "b" -  it is unrelated two string. I don't want to find them by "a b" query

Answer (score 0):

I would think the multi-value would be more accurate.

imagine a tokenized string "spider web developer"

vs

multi-value field with the values "spider" and "web developer"

a search for "web developer" would match both fields but the match vs the multi-value field could be seen as more accurate.

Comment: spider web would also be a match although he probably doesn't want it, and could be prevented with positional increments.

Comment: I know that. but my tags will note contain spaces, or I will choose diff tokenizer. the questions only about lucene scoring model